# Regex against an odd value

Tags: regex, csv, powershell

I am parsing through a csv to export into two catagories: Matches and NonMatches via powershell.

The data in the csv is formated as the following:

```
SamAccountName
xx9999xx
aa0000aa
ab0909xc
etc
```

I need a regex that will allow me to filter out all the matches that follow the aa0000bb naming convention and export that into a csv (same with the ones that dont match the aa0000bb convention)
Convention (because it's odd): the first 2 are letters ranging from a-z,then 4 numbers 0-9, then 2 letters a-z. Meaning you can have aa0000aa and by7690zi

Right now I have:

```
Import-Csv "C:\Path\to\csv" | ForEach {
$Name =$_.SamAccountName;
$Name -Match '[a-z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[a-z]+[a-z]'} | Out-Null; $Matches
```

or

```
ForEach ($Name in $CSV)
{
    If ($Name -Match '[a-z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[a-z]+[a-z]')
        {
         Write-Host "$Matches"
        }else{
         Write-Host "No Match"
        }
}
```

Both seem to output random things that are not correct. 
I'm thinking (hoping really) that there is a way to match by the following:

```
a-z #For the first set of letters
0-9 #For the 4 digits
a-z #For the second set of letters

ie [a-z{2}]+[0-9{4}]+[a-z{2}]
```

I can run a normal `'xx9999xx' -Match '[a-z]+[a-z]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[a-z]+[a-z]'` and it returns true and then

```
PS C:\Windows> $Matches

Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                  
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                  
0                              xx9999xx
```

But I still don't understand how to do that on a mass scale.

Comment: Can you provide sample inputs and outputs? Are there multiple aa0000aa per line of input?

Comment: @Arluin - No its a unique value so only one instance of aa0000aa, the next value would be aa0000ab, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct regex to match your convention should be as following.

**Regex:** `[a-z]{2}[0-9]{4}[a-z]{2}`

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mE5aR9/1)**</kbd>

Comment: So my thought was kind of close! Thank you Noob :)

Answer (score 2):

[noob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36142871/3829407) has a correct regex to match your problem. To understand why yours was matching more than you expected it is because the plus sign is a quantifier meta character in regex. It means

> Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

So if you have more numbers than two it would try to match more. So this would be a valid match

```
aaaa00000000000aaaa
```

Using a fixed quantifier `{2}`, `{4}` etc. will match exactly what you want.

[Regex101.com](http://Regex101.com) is a great resource for quick testing. It also gives a very good explanation of your regex.

Comment: Ahh, i gotcha. That Regex101 is a nifty tool. Im guessing Php and powershell are similar in the way that they handle regex? Thank you, Matt